# Pairings of Simplex Edges

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, simplex, orientation

This is an open-ended question.  If you'll allow, I'd like to keep its origins vague for the moment, so as not to bias responses.  I am interested in any and all thoughts.

There are three pairings of the numbers 0,1,2,3: $\{ 01, 23 \}, \{ 02,13 \}, \{03,12 \}$.  Sum the pairs and look at the parities: 0+1  and 2+3 are odd, 0+2 and 1+3 are even, 0+3 and 1+2 are odd.  So let's say there are two "odd pairings" and one "even pairing."

Now draw a 3-simplex, label its vertices 0, 1, 2, 3, and observe that the above pairings are pairs of opposite edges (edges not sharing a vertex).  So there is an asymmetry to the types of opposite edge pairs that a labelled 3-simplex has: it has two "odd edge pairs" and only one "even edge pair."

My question is this: Can you see some "geometric characteristic" that distinguishes the odd and even edge pairs?

Another way of asking would be: Does anything about the way that the 3-simplex sits in $\mathbb R^3$ separate its edge pairs into two kinds of pairs, similar to the above separation into "even pairs" and "odd pairs?"

I should mention that I am thinking of the vertex labeling as a way of orienting the simplex, and so I am particularly interested in responses that somehow involve orientations (but all thoughts are welcome).

Edit: Here is a better way to describe what I'm looking for.  As pointed out in the comments, the bare simplex all on its own has no edges nor pairs of edges singled out; it is symmetrical in that regard.  A labeling of vertices provides us *one way* of finding a distinguished pair of opposite edges.  What are some *other additional structures* one can impose on the 3-simplex that would single out a pair of opposite edges?  For example, choosing an orientation is a bit less structure than labeling the vertices--is an orientation sufficient to single out a pair of opposite edges?

Comment: I hadn't considered the $3$-simplex as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$. If anything, it seems more naturally a subset of $\Bbb{R}^4$. What is your embedding into $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what kind of geometric characteristic you expect to find; the geometric symmetries of the $3$-simplex do not distinguish its (pairs of) edges. So any distinguishing must be done on the basis of your chosen labeling of the vertices.

Comment: We must have different naming conventions in mind.  When I say 3-simplex I mean the simplex that is the convex hull of 4 non-coplanar points in R^3.  The standard realization in R^3 is the convex hull of the points {(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1).  That is, if I say n-simplex I mean a simplex whose dimension is n.

Comment: Regarding your second point: You are right, I must have some extra structure in mind if I'm looking to single out pairs of edges.  When I phrased the question, that extra structure is a labeling of vertices.  A specific embedding in R^3 would also qualify as extra structure, as would a choice of orientation.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: The question is too broad. I also suspect that this is not the question you want answered. Perhaps you could ask about the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: True, the question is broad. What I am after is whether anyone has seen other ways in which pairs of opposite edges get singled out.  The reason is: I am considering a problem in which it is convenient to introduce a labeling of the simplex's vertices, but this is an auxiliary choice.  Its only purpose is to provide orientations to the cells and to be a book-keeping tool.  Some quantities that live on the edges end up pairing along opposite edges, and a minus sign appeared on the distinguished "even" pair.  That was unexpected, but maybe could be understood in terms of some other phenomenon

Comment: An orientation is not enough to distinguish two pairs of opposite edges. Orientation is invariant under rotation, but you can rotate any pair of opposite edges onto any other.

Answer (score 1):

We argue in ${\mathbb Z}/(2{\mathbb Z})=\{0,1\}$. Up to symmetry there is just one way to label two vertices of a regular tetrahedron with $0$ and two vertices with $1$. Then there are two pairs of opposite sides having  sum $1$ and one pair of opposite sides having sum $0$. There is not more to it.

Comment: This answer helped me see that the way I posed my question was inadequate.  Your answer puts to rest the question: "By labeling vertices, what ways are there to find a distinguished pair of opposite edges?"  And I agree that there is not more to it.  Please see my edit, where I hope I have clarified my aims, which are to gather other types of structure the 3-simplex could carry that would distinguish opposite pairs of edges.